# What about continuity of Space and possible discreteness of Time?

Tags: spacetime, time, space, discrete

Is time continuous or discrete? Is even this question a valid question? If you say, it all depends on resolution then assume the best possible resolution achievable. If it is discrete, then what about space? More specifically, what about space-time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is reality discrete at the quantum level? (...and what does it imply not only mathematically?)](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9720/)

Comment: Thank you..that is a good explanation of "why it's not discrete" But i am asking what if time IS discrete. We know space is not. So what becomes of Space-time?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35674/2451 , http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54815/2451 and links therein.